# Python script to check if a zip file is corrupt

Tags: python, zip

How do I check if a zip file is corrupt or not? I have a zip file with 10 jpg images. I am able to extract say 8 of the images. Two of the images in the zip are corrupt and I am not able to extract those. Is there a way to check for this in a Python script?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This code will either throw an exception (if the zip file is really bad or if it's not a zip file), or show the first bad file in the zip file.

```
import sys
import zipfile

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = sys.argv[1:]

    print("Testing zip file: %s" % args[0])

    try:
        the_zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(args[0])
        ret = the_zip_file.testzip()
        if ret is not None:
            print("First bad file in zip: %s" % ret)
            sys.exit(1)
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Exception:", ex)
        sys.exit(1)

    print("Zip file is good.")
```

Comment: is there a similar way to check Winrar file?

Comment: I tested the code on a file that is not zip and I received the error: ``zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file``

Comment: That's because it's throwing an exception - you need to make sure to enclose code like this in a try/except clause.  I updated the answer to include that so the script will run standalone.

Answer (score 12):

Use the `zipfile` module `testzip` function, see http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.testzip