# Validating a zip file coming from stdin

Tags: python, zip, python-2.7

After some frustration with `unzip(1L)`, I've been trying to create a script that will unzip and print out raw data from all of the files inside a zip archive that is coming from stdin. I currently have the following, which works:

```
import sys, zipfile, StringIO

stdin = StringIO.StringIO(sys.stdin.read())
zipselect = zipfile.ZipFile(stdin)

filelist = zipselect.namelist()
for filename in filelist:
    print filename, ':' 
    print zipselect.read(filename)
```

When I try to add validation to check if it truly is a zip file, however, it doesn't like it.

```
...

zipcheck = zipfile.is_zipfile(zipselect)
if zipcheck is not None:
    print 'Input is not a zip file.'
    sys.exit(1)

...
```

results in

```
File "/home/chris/simple/zipcat/zipcat.py", line 13, in <module>
  zipcheck = zipfile.is_zipfile(zipselect)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 149, in is_zipfile
  result = _check_zipfile(fp=filename)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 135, in _check_zipfile
  if _EndRecData(fp):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 203, in _EndRecData
  fpin.seek(0, 2)
AttributeError: ZipFile instance has no attribute 'seek'
```

I assume it can't seek because it is not a file, as such?

Sorry if this is obvious, this is my first 'go' with Python.

Comment: "assume it can't seek because it is not a file, as such?"  No need to assume.  It can't seek; you can't use this method.  Why are you trying to process stdin?  Why not accept a filename?

Comment: Please check the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875747/python-script-to-check-if-a-zip-file-is-corrupt

Comment: I am using stdin and not a filename because the input is coming from `wget -qO-`. I don't want to download the file to the disk, I merely want to stream it to the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass `stdin` to `is_zipfile`, not `zipselect`.  `is_zipfile` takes a path to a file or a file object, not a `ZipFile`.

See [the zipfile.is_zipfile documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.is_zipfile)

You are correct that a `ZipFile` can't seek because it isn't a file.  It's an archive, so it can contain many files.

Answer (score 1):

To do this entirely in memory will take some work.  The `AttributeError` message means that the `is_zipfile` method is trying to use the `seek` method of the file handle you provide.  But standard input is not seekable, and therefore your file object for it has no `seek` method.

If you really, really can't store the file on disk temporarily, then you could buffer the entire file in memory (you would need to enforce a size limit for security), and then implement some "duck" code that looks and acts like a seekable file object but really just uses the byte-string in memory.

It is possible that you could cheat and buffer only enough of the data for `is_zipfile` to do its work, but I seem to recall that the table-of-contents for ZIP is at the end of the file.  I could be wrong about that though.

Comment: He is doing this in memory.  He does a `stdin.read()` to get the entire file as a `str` then wraps that `str` in a `StringIO`.  `StringIO` creates a file-like object from a `str`.

Comment: In this case, stdin in actually a StringIO object that has already read and buffered everything from sys.stdin, so it is a seekable object.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2011 python2 fragment was: StringIO.StringIO(sys.stdin.read())

In 2018 a python3 programmer might phrase that as: io.StringIO(...).

What you wanted was the following python3 fragment: io.BytesIO(...).
Certainly that works well for me when using the `requests` module to download binary ZIP files from webservers:

```
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(req.content))
```